# Dataflow eclipse example generates rateLimitExceeded error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Following the instructions for "Developing Dataflow Pipelines with the
Cloud Dataflow Plugin for Eclipse" ...

When I run the code generated by the plugin, I get this error

```
WARNING: There were problems getting current job messages: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

This is perplexing because it looks like the default quota for dataflow is 1,000 requests/second/user.

I don't think this "Hello, World" program is exceeding that limit.

I am running with the very latest version of Eclipse [Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)] using Java 8 [1.8.0_66] on Mac OS X [10.11.1 (El Capitan)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a mixup the quota for the RPC used by the `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` to check on the job status was too strictly limited. This should be fixed, and
should not have affected the behavior of a running job. Please let us know
if you continue seeing problems.

You could also avoid making these RPCs by using the `DataflowPipelineRunner`, which won't poll job status after it is submitted.